# Issues resetting the ledger HWM

Tags: ledger

I'm trying to reset the ledger baking application HWM (high watermark) to prepare it for the reset zeronet.

Trying the ledger tz1 addr I get:

```
./tezos-signer set ledger high watermark for "ledger://<tz1...>" to 0
Error:
  No Ledger found for <tz1...>
```

Trying the animal name thing I get:

```
./tezos-signer set ledger high watermark for "ledger://<animal>/ed25519/0'/0'" to 0
Error:
  Ledger Application level error (set_high_watermark): Conditions of use not satisfied
```

Getting the HWM works, but only for the animal URI ‍♂️

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ledger address required for the `set ledger high watermark` command is what is listed via the command:

```
$ ./tezos-client list connected ledgers
Found a Tezos Baking 1.5.0 (commit v1.4.3-21-gf3071161) application running on Ledger Nano S at [0001:001d:00].

To use keys at BIP32 path m/44'/1729'/0'/0' (default Tezos key path), use one of
 tezos-client import secret key ledger_<username> "ledger://<animal>/ed25519/0'/0'"
 tezos-client import secret key ledger_<username> "ledger://<animal>/secp256k1/0'/0'"
 tezos-client import secret key ledger_<username> "ledger://<animal>/P-256/0'/0'
```

So the second thing you tried is the correct method:

`$ ./tezos-client set ledger high watermark for "ledger://<animal>/ed25519/0'/0'" to 0`

That said, the error you are receiving usually means you haven't confirmed with the physical ledger that the watermark change is allowed. In other words, you may not have pressed the button on the ledger to confirm the change. Yes, there is a **physical** confirmation on the ledger required to change the high watermark. This is presumably to prevent someone with shell access without physical access to the ledger to cause double baking/endorsing.

Comment: ‍♂️ it was the physical conformation for sure  You should have seen me punching in the command and running full speed from my desk to the server room to confirm  Thanks!!

Comment: FYI `authorize ledger to bake` is not required for `set ledger high watermark` to work

Comment: Thanks @ElliotCameron, I removed that piece of the answer.